# SQLite UNIQUE constraint dependent on another column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a Java file that creates a subjects table in SQLite like so:

```
public static final String CREATE_SUBJECTS_TABLE = "create table " + SUBJECTS_TABLE_NAME +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,SUBJECT TEXT,LEVEL INTEGER)";
db.execSQL(CREATE_SUBJECTS_TABLE);
```

If I wanted to make SUBJECT TEXT unique I could edit it to say SUBJECT TEXT UNIQUE, however this would mean I couldn't have the same subject at multiple levels. I want a way to be able to have the same subject at multiple levels, but not have a repeat of a subject with the same level. A UNIQUE constraint, but only within subjects with the same value in the level column.

I was wondering if there is a built in way to do this, or if I'll have to code it myself. If so, is there a common syntax that I should be using to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you actually want the `(subject, level)` pair to be unique. That would let you have duplicate subjects as long as the levels were different but duplicate subjects with the same level would not be allowed. A standard `unique` constraint supports this so you could add `unique(subject, level)` at the end of your table's definition:

```
public static final String CREATE_SUBJECTS_TABLE = "create table " + SUBJECTS_TABLE_NAME + " (..., unique(subject, level))";
```

Comment: Oh awesome, was unaware that unique could do that. Thanks!